# *** stack smashing detected *** with double array in double for cycle

Tags: c

As the title says im hitting stack smashing detected with my code.
The weird thing i cannot understand is that it outputs all the positions of the moons correctly and then it stack smashes. When i set the limit to 2 it only outputs 2 positions but doesnt stack smash.
I have tried increasing the array size to see if that would help but it does not help at all.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int input[4][3] = {5, 4, 4, -11, -11, -3, 0, 7, 0, -13, 2, 10};
struct Moons
{
int position[2];
int velocity[2];
};

int main()
{
struct Moons moon[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        moon[i].position[x] = input[i][x];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in `C` start at an index of `0` and end at the index "size-1". So, in your code, the `moon[3]` array has elements: `moon[0]`, `moon[1]` and `moon[2]` - but your outer `i` loop runs even when `i` has the value `3` - so you are trying to reference an element of an array beyond its bounds.  And similarly for your inner `x` loop.

Comment: Ahhh i totally missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers to specify when declaring arrays in C is not the maximun index but the number of elements. Allocate enough elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int input[4][3] = {5, 4, 4, -11, -11, -3, 0, 7, 0, -13, 2, 10};
struct Moons
{
int position[3]; /* increase this */
int velocity[2]; /* not used, but should be increased too? */
};

int main()
{
struct Moons moon[4]; /* increase this */
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        moon[i].position[x] = input[i][x];
    }
}
}
```

Note that accessing out-of-bounds of array invokes *undefined behavior*. Stack smashing detection nor Segmentation Fault need not occur even if out-of-bounds write exists.

Comment: Indeed this was an issue too. Combining the two solution the code now works. Thank you.